# CREATE TABLE ... LIKE not working

Tags: sql, create-table

Need help trying to create a table using `CREATE TABLE ... LIKE`, code is below, error given is

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'LIKE'

```
CREATE TABLE jobserve_reports LIKE Jobserve
```

I've tried putting the `LIKE` in quotations with no luck, tried making it a temporary table, using curly braces and nothing has worked. Am at my wits end.

Comment: LIKE and Create Table cant be used together

Comment: Please specify your dbms.

Comment: @apomene, you can in [mysql](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-like.html)

Comment: I think MySQL and Postgres (and related databases) are the only databases that support `create table . . . like` syntax.

Comment: @HoneyBadger Interesting I did not know that!!!

Comment: What database engine are you using? Can you please write down what is the table structure that you want create: what fields,...

Comment: Which [DBMS product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a tag for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Comment: For Postgres you need to put the `like` between parentheses: `create table jobserve_reports (LIKE Jobserve);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `SQL Server`, we can create using:

```
SELECT * 
INTO newtable 
FROM oldtable 
WHERE 1 = 0;
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked. Do you know why LIKE isn't working?

Comment: The LIKE operator is used in a WHERE clause to search for a specified pattern in a column. You can find more details here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/like-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Also if it solved your query can you accept this as answer by clicking the tick button. Thank You.

Answer (score 2):

If LIKE is not  available in your db you could use create select

```
CREATE TABLE jobserve_reports AS 
select * from  Jobserve
```

or equivalent

eventuallly using

```
CREATE TABLE jobserve_reports AS 
select * from  Jobserve
where 1 = 2
```

for get no result

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name  correct  .. answer  updated .

Answer (score 1):

For [Postgres](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-createtableas.html), [MS sql-server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-as-select-azure-sql-data-warehouse?view=aps-pdw-2016) and [Oracle](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/tables/create_table2.php) use the `AS` keyword:

```
CREATE TABLE new_table
    AS SELECT * FROM old_table;
```

---

In [MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-select.html) you can use the `AS` keyword as well, but it is optional:

```
CREATE TABLE new_table
    AS SELECT * FROM old_table;
```

or

```
CREATE TABLE new_table
    SELECT * FROM old_table;
```

Comment: Actually Postgres **does** support like: `create table foo (like bar)`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Hm... you are right, that is also supported. TIL something new. I always used `as`.

Comment: They serve two different purposes. `create table as ...` creates a table based on the result of a query. `create table (like ..)` create a table based on a different table definition (including constraints and indexes). Plus `create table as` is standard SQL

Comment: It makes sense, to offer different options for the different use cases